# Django 1.9.5: FieldError for reverse lookup fields occasionally

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I'm getting a frustrating intermittent error in Django, when attempting to run the `objects.all()` for a `Queryset` that is prefetching. There is an issue where occasionally the `model._meta` seems to be missing fields, between instantiation of a queryset and running an iteration through it. It's almost as if the queryset's prefetch doesn't actually get run in time for the iteration of the list of objects.

In this example, data.service_log is simply a queryset with some prefetched items called `servicelog`. When I run the queryset in the shell, I can look at all the fields in the `self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())` method on the queryset. They are all there, specifically the "servicelog."

Notice this Traceback for this error it says that "servicelog" is not an available field, yet it lists it in the list of fields to choose from. This seems to be a Django bug, but I can't be sure because I can't explain or isolate the behavior. I can't possibly be the only person getting this error. It seems to be in `django/db/models/sql/query.py` in the `names_to_paths()` method. Here's the code that is failing to resolve:

```
query.py names_to_paths():

field = None
try:
    field = opts.get_field(name)
except FieldDoesNotExist:
    if name in self.annotation_select:
        field = self.annotation_select[name].output_field

if field is not None:
    # Fields that contain one-to-many relations with a generic
    # model (like a GenericForeignKey) cannot generate reverse
    # relations and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying.
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
        raise FieldError(
            "Field %r does not generate an automatic reverse "
            "relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse "
            "querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider "
            "adding a GenericRelation." % name
        )
    try:
        model = field.model._meta.concrete_model
    except AttributeError:
        model = None
else:
    # We didn't find the current field, so move position back
    # one step.
    pos -= 1
    if pos == -1 or fail_on_missing:
        field_names = list(get_field_names_from_opts(opts))
        available = sorted(field_names + list(self.annotation_select))
        raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword %r into field. "
                         "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", .join(available)))
    break
```

`field does not get set in the first try, then the condition statement`if field is not None`fails so we enter the`else`block. There the`pos`gets reduced by one, but since this field is 'servicelog' it is already at 0. However, when I try this in the shell, it always finds the`field`with`opts.get_field('servicelog')`. Only when run from WSGI and Apache2 does this failure occur. Again, it isn't all the time, which makes it extremely difficult to test. I'm perplexed by this, and am not sure where to look for clues. PLEASE if anybody has ANY ideas of what to explore, I'd be so appreciative.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/www/fast/services/views/edit.py", line 12897, in service_log
    for service in data.service_log:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _fetch_all
    self._prefetch_related_objects()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 656, in _prefetch_related_objects
    prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, self._prefetch_related_lookups)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1457, in prefetch_related_objects
    obj_list, additional_lookups = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, lookup, level)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1556, in prefetch_one_level
    prefetcher.get_prefetch_queryset(instances, lookup.get_current_queryset(level)))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 802, in get_prefetch_queryset
    queryset = queryset._next_is_sticky().filter(**query)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1149, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1035, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1330, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'servicelog' into field. Choices are: additional_county_worker_notes, adoption_disrupted, adoption_first_name, adoption_last_name, adoption_middle_name, adoption_placement_date, adoption_placement_reason, adoption_placement_reason_id, adoption_placement_type, adoption_risk_level, adoption_risk_level_id, adoption_termination_date, adoption_termination_destination, adoption_termination_reason, adoption_termination_reason_id, adoptive_placement, agency, agency_id, all_items_outstanding, all_items_past_due, appeal_process_date, attached_file, attends_college, attorney_email_address, attorney_email_address_id, attorney_fax, attorney_fax_id, attorney_investigator_email_address, attorney_investigator_email_address_id, attorney_investigator_fax, attorney_investigator_fax_id, attorney_investigator_name, attorney_investigator_phone, attorney_investigator_phone_id, attorney_name, attorney_phone, attorney_phone_id, blood_related_to_applicants, blood_relationship, casa_email_address, casa_email_address_id, casa_fax, casa_fax_id, casa_name, casa_phone, casa_phone_id, certification_items_outstanding, certification_items_past_due, classification, classification_id, client, client_id, county_adoption_worker, county_adoption_worker_cell, county_adoption_worker_cell_id, county_adoption_worker_email_address, county_adoption_worker_email_address_id, county_adoption_worker_fax, county_adoption_worker_fax_id, county_adoption_worker_office, county_adoption_worker_office_id, county_adoption_worker_phone, county_adoption_worker_phone_id, county_adoption_worker_title, county_case_number, county_worker, county_worker_cell, county_worker_cell_id, county_worker_email_address, county_worker_email_address_id, county_worker_fax, county_worker_fax_id, county_worker_office, county_worker_office_id, county_worker_phone, county_worker_phone_id, county_worker_title, court, court_case_name, court_case_number, court_department, court_id, created, current_grade, date_identified_adoptive, date_placed_with_home, deleted, discharge_summary, eligibility_worker, eligibility_worker_email_address, eligibility_worker_email_address_id, eligibility_worker_phone, eligibility_worker_phone_id, emergency_placement, employed_80_hours, enable_discharge_summary, expected_type, expected_type_id, extended_family_contact_allowed, final_payment_amount, finalization_date, foreign_placement, hearing_36626_date, homestudy, id, incident_placement_1, incident_placement_2, incident_placement_3, incident_placement_4, individualized_plan_review, inhousemove, interpretive_summary, item_due, items_approved, items_pending, items_rejected, items_update_requested, la_county_id, medi_cal, medi_cal_eligibility_phone, medi_cal_eligibility_phone_id, medi_cal_eligibility_worker, medi_cal_id, modified, monthly_monitored_visit_hours, mother_child, move_in_type, move_out_type, new_protective_custody_petition, non_minor_dependent, non_truant, notes, number_of_files_required, other_school_contact, other_school_contact_first_name, other_school_contact_last_name, parent_payment_override_annually, parent_payment_override_daily, parent_payment_override_monthly, parental_contact_allowed, parental_group, parental_group_id, payment_amount, percent_certified, percent_items_complete, person_number, placement, placement_date, placement_id, placement_payment_override_annually, placement_payment_override_daily, placement_payment_override_monthly, placement_reason, placement_reason_details, placement_reason_id, placement_self, placer_shelter_bed, prior_placement, progress_summary, projected_adoption_36626_date, projected_adoption_finalization_date, projected_adoption_placement_date, recordreview, requires_educational_support, requires_mental_health_services, respite, school, school_different, school_id, school_liaison_email, school_liaison_first_name, school_liaison_last_name, school_liaison_phone, school_liaison_phone_extension, school_notes, serial_number, servicecontact_onbehalf, servicedeliverylog, servicelog, social_worker_at_termination, social_worker_at_termination_id, special_health_care_needs, state_case_number, teachers, termination_date, termination_destination, termination_reason, termination_reason_details, termination_reason_id, therapist, therapy_code, therapy_supervision_requirements, treatment_abilities, treatment_needs, treatment_preferences, treatment_strengths, treatmentneed, update_requested, update_requested_by, update_requested_by_id, update_requested_date, update_requested_note, updateable, use_number_required, uses_psychotropic_medication, visit_frequency_override, visit_frequency_override_id, visitation_restrictions, who_can_pickup_at_home, who_can_pickup_at_school, who_can_visit
```

**UPDATE - adding models/offending view code**

```
models.py
class ParentalGroup(models.Model):
    many fields...

class Placement(models.Model):
    parental_group = models.ForeignKey(ParentalGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    many more fields...

class ServiceLog(models.Model):
    parental_group = models.ForeignKey(ParentalGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    placement = models.ManyToManyField(Placement, blank=True)
    many more fields...


views.py:
data.service_log = ServiceLog.objects.filter(
    parental_group=data.pg,
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'placement',
        queryset=Placement.objects.all(),
        to_attr='placements'
    ),
)

for service in data.service_log:
    some code to generate data to pass to template...

return render_to_response(...)
```

Comment: Can you share your models ?

Comment: I don't think it will help, but sure. I'll add the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem using Django 1.8.6 on Gunicorn/Django runserver. I haven't managed to reproduce the error in shell/notebook environment either.

I solved the randomly occurring FieldError by adding [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the `ManyToManyField`. I used [a through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) in the ManyToManyField though.

In your case:

```
class ServiceLog(models.Model):
    parental_group = models.ForeignKey(ParentalGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    placement = models.ManyToManyField(Placement, blank=True, related_name='servicelog')
```

Jan

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response. Sounds like it might work. I hadn't usually added the related name, since Django does it automatically. I'll try it and accept the solution if it seems to work. May be a few days before I know for sure.

Comment: So far, it has been MUCH improved. I've gotten two or three in two days. It was getting to be 20-30 per day. I'm going to continue to monitor for a week or so. I appreciate your help so much, if this solves the problem!

Comment: We are also facing this issue randomly, Please explain the reason of this issue ?